# Set different timeout for different session variables in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, session-state, session-timeout, session-cookies

Is this possible to set different timeout for different session in ASP.Net?

**Edited**
I mean that in the same page i have 2 session variable Session["ss1"] and Session["ss2"], is there possible to set timeout for each session? Or is there anyway to do the same like save session to cookie and set expire?
Sry im just new to ASP.Net

Comment: more information is needed to understand your question

Comment: what is your meaning `different`?

Comment: Did you checked: http://forums.asp.net/t/1563991.aspx/1 ?

Comment: Its not possible in current .Net Framework versions, But Microsoft should think about this in next version :)

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a very simple extender class that does that. You can find the source code [here](http://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/196-aspnet-session-caching-expiring-values/)

Usage:

```
//store and expire after 5 minutes
Session.AddWithTimeout("key", "value", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

Answer (score 3):

Set any timeout at login time, you can set different timeout for different users...

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = 540;
```

Comment: KamalaPrakash it I set session timeout in this way. won't it look in web.config any more?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about session timeout for different users then
You can use `Global.asax`  in this you can use `Session_Start` event  and in this event you can set session timeout differently for different users

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no the session timeout applies to ALL session variables per user. You can however use the cache or a cookie which both support timeout on an individua(per key) level.

But hang on those solutions don't come without some major drawbacks. If you use the cache you lose the privacy the session provides and if you use the cookie you are constrained with file size and serialization issues.

One workaround for this is to use the cache and make sure you include the user's session id in every key you use. This way you'll end up with a cache storage that mimics the session itself.

If you want further functionality and don't want to bother about implementing this however you can use the API from this little project on CodePlex:

http://www.univar.codeplex.com

The version 2.0 offers many storage type options out of the box including a session bound cache.

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <summary>
/// this class saves something to the Session object
/// but with an EXPIRATION TIMEOUT
/// (just like the ASP.NET Cache)
/// (c) Jitbit 2011. MIT license
/// usage sample:
///  Session.AddWithTimeout(
///   "key",
///   "value",
///   TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
/// </summary>
public static class SessionExtender
{
  public static void AddWithTimeout(
    this HttpSessionState session,
    string name,
    object value,
    TimeSpan expireAfter)
  {
    session[name] = value;
    session[name + "ExpDate"] = DateTime.Now.Add(expireAfter);
  }

  public static object GetWithTimeout(
    this HttpSessionState session,
    string name)
  {
    object value = session[name];
    if (value == null) return null;

    DateTime? expDate = session[name + "ExpDate"] as DateTime?;
    if (expDate == null) return null;

    if (expDate < DateTime.Now)
    {
      session.Remove(name);
      session.Remove(name + "ExpDate");
      return null;
    }

    return value;
  }
}
Usage:

//store and expire after 5 minutes
Session.AddWithTimeout("key", "value", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

//get the stored value
Session.GetWithTimeout("key");
```

by Alex. CEO, founder https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/196-aspnet-session-caching-expiring-values/