# How do I keep timeout time of different session variables different

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am using two session variables `sessionLogin` and `sessionPageName`. `SessionLogin` will hold login name of the user who logs in and `sessionPageName` will holds the name of a page that is currently loaded. As the `sessionLogin` timeout occurs, the page is redirected to login page. The purpose of `sessionPageName` is to redirect the user to the page user had last viewed before timeout of `sessionLogin` had occurred.

My question is if `sessionLogin` expires, will `sessionPageName` also expire given that session timeout interval is after 20 minutes? How can I increase the time out period of `sessionPageName` to, say, 30 minutes and keep the life of `sessionLogin` to default?

Alternatively, is there a way in asp.net C# to take the user to the last page they viewed before `sessionLogin` expired that resulted in direct to login page in my code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069502/set-different-timeout-for-different-session-variables-in-asp-net

Comment: You should probably learn how Forms Authentication works in ASP.NET. It sounds like you're trying to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If if are using `FormAuthentication` the you are looking for `ReturnUrl`.

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage
```

(which uses that very ReturnUrl QueryString parameter)

[FormAuthentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.redirectfromloginpage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) msdn link

Comment: thanks for your comment. i did it your way. i have a master page using form and formsauthentication is being used in its contentplaceholder. But when session expires and user is redirected to login page, after user logins, the user is shown home page insted of page he last has browsed before he is redirected to login page. am i missing something??

Comment: are you using formauthentication?

Comment: i have kept login user name and password in session and used FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(loginName, true); to redirect to home page. Now, as session expires, the user is redirected to login page. here, again when user enters login name and password, he is directed to home page but i wanted him to direct to page he last viewed. my web.config tag is ::   <authentication mode="Forms">      
      <forms defaultUrl="~/Home.aspx" loginUrl="~/default.aspx">
        </forms>
      </authentication>

Comment: yaa. my master page uses form and i am using form authentication in  its contentplaceholder page

Comment: when there is session time out it redirects to `default.aspx` with one query string parameter `ReturnUrl`. Are you getting this parameter in query string?

Comment: thanks shekhar. did some research on formauthentication and now its working the way i wanted..